# Snowflake: CTE with clause Insert statement error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, with-statement, snowflake-schema

I am using CTE with clause in Snowflake and trying to insert records into the target table ent.P_ACCOUNTS_EXTRACT_SHR.
But a compilation error throwing while executing the query.

Error: syntax error line 27 at position 4 unexpected 'INSERT'.

I am using two CTE temp_product and latest_custodian and then inserting into the target table.

```
with temp_Product 
    AS (
        select Product_EDW_Id From ent.PRODUCT
    Where 
      PRODUCT_CLASS_NM IN ('Individual', 'Composite')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R.Participating_Product_EDW_Id FROM ent.PRODUCT p
    INNER JOIN ent.Product_Group_Relationship R
    ON P.PRODUCT_EDW_ID = R.PRODUCT_EDW_ID
    ),
 Latest_Custodian
    AS (
    SELECT 
        c.Src_Sys_Custodian_Account_Id, 
        c.client_edw_id, 
        c.Create_dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.Src_Sys_Custodian_Account_Id, c.client_edw_id 
                          ORDER BY c.Create_dt DESC) as RNUM1
    FROM ent.Product P
        INNER JOIN temp_Product TP
        ON P.Product_EDW_Id = TP.Product_EDW_Id
    Left Join ent.custodian C
    ON P.UDF7_TX = C.SRC_SYS_CUSTODIAN_ACCOUNT_ID AND 
        P.CLIENT_EDW_ID = C.CLIENT_EDW_ID
    )
    
    INSERT INTO ent.P_ACCOUNTS_EXTRACT_SHR (
        IS_FLAG,
        CREATE_DT,
        ACCOUNT_CODE,
        TRADABLE_DATE,
        CLOSE_DATE,
        ACCOUNT_TYPE,
        TRUST_OFFICER,
        TRUST_OFFICER_CITY,
        TRUST_OFFICER_PHONE,
        STATEMENT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        CUSTODIAN_CODE,
        CUSTODIAN,
        TAXABLE,
        ACCOUNT_ATTRIBUTE,
        ACCOUNT_NAME 
    )
    SELECT 
        '0',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
        P.Client_Product_Id,
        P.INCEPTION_DT,
        P.src_sys_close_dt,
        P.UDF31_TX,
        P.UDF15_TX,
        P.UDF16_TX,
        P.UDF17_TX,
        P.UDF7_TX,
        C1.custodian_mnemonic_nm,
        P.UDF8_TX,
        P.tax_exempt_fl,
        P.udf35_tx,
        P.PRODUCT_NM
    from ent.PRODUCT P
    INNER JOIN temp_Product TP
    ON P.Product_EDW_Id = TP.Product_EDW_Id
    LEFT JOIN Latest_Custodian C
    ON P.UDF7_TX = C.SRC_SYS_CUSTODIAN_ACCOUNT_ID AND
        P.client_edw_id = C.client_edw_id AND
        RNUM1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN ent.CUSTODIAN C1
    ON C.SRC_SYS_CUSTODIAN_ACCOUNT_ID = C1.src_sys_custodian_account_id AND
    C.create_dt = C1.CREATE_DT
    ORDER BY P.product_structure_level_nm;
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO ...
WITH cte AS (...)
SELECT ...
FROM cte;
```

Sample:

[image]